# Calculations on parsed JSON values produce NaN

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I have a problem with some code. I started building a plugin for Chroma to insert data using JSON, but NaN is displayed to me.

My file content.js

```
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://rlinkit.neteasy.pl/abc.json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myArr= Array();
        var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
    for (i in arr) {
        for(j in arr[i] ){
            for(p in arr[i][j]){
                out = arr[i][j][p].currency + arr[i][j][p].code + arr[i][j][p].bid + arr[i][j][p].ask + '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

My CodeHTML:

```
<div id="id01"></div>

<script src="content.js"></script>
```

My Output:

[image]

Edit (When I give the code - nothing is displayed.):

```
function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    var j;
    var p;
    for (var i = 0; i in arr.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j in arr[i].length; j++ ){
            for(var p = 0; p in arr[i][j].length; p++){
                out += arr[i][j][p].currency + arr[i][j][p].code + arr[i][j][p].buy + arr[i][j][p].sell + '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Comment: It means the values in your array are neither numbers nor coercible into numbers. Probably `null` or `undefined`. Inspect your data in devtools: right-click inside the page and click "inspect".

Comment: For one, you're not setting values of iterators, or the increment. I'm unaware of any js shorthand that omits that `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`

Comment: @JoelHager 
I edited my message when I do as you indicate, nothing is displayed.

Comment: @JoelHager for...in loops are valid JS, but they're used to iterate over keys in an object, not items in an array. Your syntax is correct, but OP has copied it incorrectly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over a JavaScript array, either use a [for ... of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop or a traditional [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop. The syntax in your updated function (specifically, `i in arr.length`) is invalid JavaScript (looks like Python?).

Providing example data would help to improve this answer, but try some version of the following (updated to use ES6 `let` syntax, which you may want to revert to `var`):

```
function myFunction(arr) {
    let out = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            for (let p = 0; p < arr[i][j].length; p++) {
                out += arr[i][j][p].currency + arr[i][j][p].code + arr[i][j][p].buy + arr[i][j][p].sell + "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Comment: try adding `console.log`s to each loop to see what data you're getting in each iteration (eg, `console.log(arr[i])` in the outer loop, `console.log(arr[i][j])` in the loop inside that one). or better yet, use `debugger` so you can try out different values in the console